# Topology when the head has less edges than the body

Tags: animation, rigging, armature, edit-mode, topology

So, I created the head and body separately,  not noticing that the number of edges at the base of the head was less than that in the body. If I try to Create more edges by adding edge loops, some parts become dense with unnecessary edge loops. So I just used tris to join them forcefully. But why do I think this joint will get messed up during animation?
[image]

Comment: It's not very clean but if you don't see any bad shading/pinching/artefacts, then you don't have to worry I guess

Comment: @moonboots Will it be a problem when I rigify it?

Comment: not particularly

Comment: @moonboots Will it deform badly when I rig it using head and neck bones from rigify?

Comment: I don't think so, maybe share your file

Comment: @moonboots https://filebin.net/whoqycsletdwznzf/GEO_FEMALE_TUTO.blend

Comment: it's almost imperceptible, it looks a bit like a skin fold, so you should not care, in my opinion you don't need so many faces, you could remove some edges and give a Subdivision Surface modifier to your object, but anyway it would take time and it wouldn't fix your joint problem, so maybe leave it as it is?

Comment: @moonboots Actually I just applied the subdivision modifier and if I try to reverse it, the topology kept getting messed up. Are you sure there's no problem with the neck movement after animating it, using this topology?